# In OpenSSL are the Error Stack and the Error Queue the same?

Tags: openssl

In the openSSL documentation I keep reading Error Queue and Error Stack.
Are both descriptions referring to the same mechanism? or are they different mechanisms?

Answer (score 2):

> I keep reading Error Queue and Error Stack. Are both descriptions referring to the same mechanism? or are they different mechanisms?

As I understand them, they are the same, give or take. They can mostly be used interchangeably.

The *Error Queue* is logical, and its usually be discussed abstractly. The library has at least two distinct error queues. The first is the one from `libcrypto`, and you fetch its errors with `ERR_get_error`. The second is the one from `libssl`, and you fetch errors with `SSL_get_error`.

The *Error Stack* is actually an implementation of the error queue. Here's what `libcrypto`'s looks like in code. Its declared in `crypto/err/err.h`, and implemented in `crypto/err/err.c`:

```
unsigned long ERR_get_error(void)
{
    return (get_error_values(1, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));
}
```

And:

```
static unsigned long get_error_values(int inc, int top, const char **file,
                                      int *line, const char **data,
                                      int *flags)
{
    int i = 0;
    ERR_STATE *es;
    unsigned long ret;

    es = ERR_get_state();

    if (inc && top) {
        if (file)
            *file = "";
        if (line)
            *line = 0;
        if (data)
            *data = "";
        if (flags)
            *flags = 0;

        return ERR_R_INTERNAL_ERROR;
    }

    if (es->bottom == es->top)
        return 0;
    if (top)
        i = es->top;            /* last error */
    else
        i = (es->bottom + 1) % ERR_NUM_ERRORS; /* first error */

    ret = es->err_buffer[i];
    if (inc) {
        es->bottom = i;
        es->err_buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    if ((file != NULL) && (line != NULL)) {
        if (es->err_file[i] == NULL) {
            *file = "NA";
            if (line != NULL)
                *line = 0;
        } else {
            *file = es->err_file[i];
            if (line != NULL)
                *line = es->err_line[i];
        }
    }

    if (data == NULL) {
        if (inc) {
            err_clear_data(es, i);
        }
    } else {
        if (es->err_data[i] == NULL) {
            *data = "";
            if (flags != NULL)
                *flags = 0;
        } else {
            *data = es->err_data[i];
            if (flags != NULL)
                *flags = es->err_data_flags[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And:

```
ERR_STATE *ERR_get_state(void)
{
    static ERR_STATE fallback;
    ERR_STATE *ret, tmp, *tmpp = NULL;
    int i;
    CRYPTO_THREADID tid;

    err_fns_check();
    CRYPTO_THREADID_current(&tid);
    CRYPTO_THREADID_cpy(&tmp.tid, &tid);
    ret = ERRFN(thread_get_item) (&tmp);

    /* ret == the error state, if NULL, make a new one */
    if (ret == NULL) {
        ret = (ERR_STATE *)OPENSSL_malloc(sizeof(ERR_STATE));
        if (ret == NULL)
            return (&fallback);
        CRYPTO_THREADID_cpy(&ret->tid, &tid);
        ret->top = 0;
        ret->bottom = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < ERR_NUM_ERRORS; i++) {
            ret->err_data[i] = NULL;
            ret->err_data_flags[i] = 0;
        }
        tmpp = ERRFN(thread_set_item) (ret);
        /* To check if insertion failed, do a get. */
        if (ERRFN(thread_get_item) (ret) != ret) {
            ERR_STATE_free(ret); /* could not insert it */
            return (&fallback);
        }
        /*
         * If a race occured in this function and we came second, tmpp is the
         * first one that we just replaced.
         */
        if (tmpp)
            ERR_STATE_free(tmpp);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And here is where the list of error states is declared:

```
$ grep -IR ERR_STATE * | grep DECLARE
crypto/err/err.c:DECLARE_LHASH_OF(ERR_STATE);
```

Comment: `ERR_*` is a queue, and mostly used for actual errors. `SSL_get_error()` is separate, but not a queue; it is a single small-integer value and used both for true errors and cases that are valid but need to be distinguished; a more accurate but less convenient name would be `SSL_get_any_status_other_than_fully_normal_completion_of_operation()`.

Comment: Just checking my understanding. If I take SSL_read() as an example: before calling SSL_read() I call ERR_clear_error(), then I call SSL_read() and if the return from SSL_read() <= 0 then I would call SSL_get_error(). Question: After I call SSL_get_error(), do I still need to check ERR_print_error_cd() to make sure that I get all possible error messages?